# Elements of quotient group with $\mathbb Z$-basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group, free-abelian-group

Abelian free group $G, H$ have rank $2$ and $G$ has $\Bbb Z$-basis $x, y$, if $H$ has $\Bbb Z$-basis
$$2x+y, 2x-3y$$ then what are the elements of $G/ H$ ?

I am new to the topics, so don't know how to start. The question is motivated from the following excerpt of the book Algebraic-Number Theory by Ian Stewart and David Tall, on page 30 -

> for example, if $G$ has rank $3$ and $\Bbb Z$-basis $x, y, z$; and if $H$ has $\Bbb Z$-basis
> $$3x+y-2z,
> 4x-5y+ z,
> x +7z,$$
> then $|G/ H|$ is the absolute value of
> $\begin{bmatrix}
> 3 & 1 & -2\\
> 4 & -5 & 1\\
> 1 & 0 & 7
> \end{bmatrix}$,
> namely 142.

I wanted to know  what are the elements of quotient group $G/H$, and asked it but since it has a large  order i have modified to my present question.

Comment: Do you know the *definition* of the quotient group?

Comment: @LeeMosher yes, for example for rank of 1, I can construct, but having hard time to figure with rank $> 1$.

Comment: The relevant theorem is that if $f\colon\mathbb{Z}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}^n$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-hom, then $\operatorname{coker}(f)$ is finite iff $\det(f)\neq0$ and in that case, $|\operatorname{coker}(f)|=|\det(f)|$. The $f$ here is the mapping $x\mapsto 2x+y,y\mapsto 2x-3y$. In this specific case, you can try doing this explicitly by diagonalizing the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $G$ is a free Abelian group over a two-element set $\{x,y\}$ and $H$ is the subgroup of $G$ generated by $2x+y$ and $2x-3y$. It is easy to check that $H$ has rank $2$. The theorem on subgroups of a finitely generated free Abelian group (see, for instance, [§20, Kur]) implies that there exist bases $\{u_1,u_2\}$ and $\{v_1,v_2\}$ of the groups $G$ and $H$, such that $v_1=k_1u_1$ and $v_2=k_2u_2$ for some natural numbers $k_1|k_2$. It follows that $G/H$ is isomorphic a direct product of cyclic groups of orders $k_1$ and $k_2$.

The numbers $k_1$ and $k_2$ can be found as follows. Let $u_1=a_{11}x+a_{12}y$, $u_2=a_{21}x+a_{22}y$, and $A=\|a_{ij}\|$, $1\le i,j\le 2$. Since $\{u_1,u_2\}$ is a basis of the group $G$, there exist integers $b_{ij}$, $1\le i,j\le 2$ such that $x=b_{11}u_1+b_{12}u_2$ and $y=b_{21}u_1+b_{22}u_2$. It follows $BA=I$, where $B=\|b_{ij}\|$, $1\le i,j\le 2$, the matrix $A$ is invertible.

[Cauchy-Binet formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula) implies that if $M$ is an integer $n\times n$ matrix and $A$ and is an invertible $n\times n$ integer matrix then matrices $M$ and $MA$ have the same divisors $d_1,\dots, d_k$, where $d_i$ is the greatest common divisors of minors of $i$-th order of the matrix.

Since $$\begin{pmatrix}k_1 & 0\\ 0 & k_2\end{pmatrix} A=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1\\ 2 & -3\end{pmatrix},$$
$k_1=\gcd (2,1,2,-2)=1$ and $k_1k_2=\gcd\det  \begin{pmatrix}2 & 1\\ 2 & -3\end{pmatrix}=8$.

*References*

[Kur] A. G. Kurosh, *Group theory*, 3nd ed., Nauka, Moskow, 1967. (in Russian)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but could you plz literary wtite down those 8 elements of the quotient group $G/H$ explicitly?

Comment: @Andrew Elements of the quotient group $G/H$ are cosets $g+H$, where $g\in G$. Since order of $G/H$ is small, we can find the set of representatives of the classes directly.  Namely, since $2x+y\in H$, each coset $g+H$ contains an element $ax+by$, where $a,b\ge 0$. Moreover, subtracting from the representative $2x-3y$ we can always assure that $a<2$. Since $4y=(2x+3y)-(2x+y)\in H$, a set $R=\{0, y, 2y,3y, x, x+y,x+2y,x+3y\}$ contains all representatives of cosets of $G/H$ and each of the cosets has exactly one representative, since there are $8=|R|$ cosets.

Comment: @Andrew Sorry, I don’t see the question to be so good and clear to be upvoted. But I voted to reopen it.